# Java using an object from a central class

Tags: java

I am making a game in Java and I have a central(Engine) class which will render the scenery/player/etc.

In the Engine class I create my player object like so

```
public class Engine() {

    public static Player player;

    public Engine() {
        RenderPlayer();
    }

    protected static void RenderPlayer() {
        player = new Player();
    }
}
```

I also have a Canvas class which handles the drawing of the player.
I want to be able to call the Players functions without having to create a new instance( since I created the player in the Engine class ). Whenever I try to use a function from the player, I get a null pointer expection.

This is how I call it.

```
Engine.player.tick();
```

I have spent a couple hours trying to figure it out, May someone tell me what I am doing wrong, and help me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: There are many answers here, and most will be correct. But an engine should be an object instance, and `renderPlayer()` should not be static. Java is an object oriented language, `static` fields (or more precisely class fields) should be used sparingly and with care.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Engine.RenderPlayer()` prior calling `Engine.player.tick();` as this method assigns a new `Player` instance to the static `player` attribute. Before you call this method `player` is null and it is causing your `NullPointerException`.

You can fix this issue by simply changing:

```
public static Player player;
```

to:

```
public static Player player = new Player();
```

Comment: aha :) thank you, I just needed to call RenderPlayer before my RenderCanvas function. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

player is null if you never create an instance of Engine because `RenderPlayer()` is in the constructor of Engine.

You could just do

```
public static Player player = new Player();
```

or make sure to call `RenderPlayer()` explicitly before accessing player.